# add calendar to google app engine based website

Tags: google-app-engine, calendar

I need to add a calendar to my GAE based website so that user can select both the date and the time.
It does not need to be the google calendar. 
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) jquery addon meets your needs.